# Использование Where для проверки нескольких значений C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

У меня есть список значений

```
 var CurPareID = _context.PareSubgroups.Where(p => p.Subgroup_Id == StudentSubgrId).Select(p => p.Pare_Id).ToList();
```

И вот такой запрос

```
ViewBag.monday_item = _context.Schedules
                           .Include(p => p.PairTime)
                           .Include(p => p.Semester)
                           .Include(p => p.Subject)
                           .Include(p => p.Teacher)
                .Where(p => p.Teacher_Id ==TeacherId);
```

Я хочу при помощи Where проверить есть ли значения из списка в контексте но он предназначен только для одного значения .Как мне проверить вмещает ли моя контекст в себе все  эти значения. И есть ли какой то аналог ON из Sql для C#.

Comment: `.Contains`, если ничего не путаю

Comment: `.Where(p => CurPareID.Contains(p.Teacher_Id))`

Comment: `CurPareID`- т. к. это список, название должно быть во множественном числе: `CurPareIDs`.

Comment: Да действительно мне помог .Contains. Спасибо а помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно было просто использовать `.Contains`

```
  ViewBag.monday_item = _context.Schedules
                                   .Include(p => p.PairTime)
                                   .Include(p => p.Semester)
                                   .Include(p => p.Subject)
                                   .Include(p => p.Teacher)
                        .Where(p => CurPareIDs.Contains(p.Id));
```